# Use of "for" or "in"

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct form:

"... *[something]* was observed **for** all cases."

"... *[something]* was observed **in** all cases."

I would bet it's the 2nd form, but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Both are "correct".  Choice depends on the specifics of what's being discussed.

Comment: Have you done any research? Can you share it with us?

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks! Would you give me a couple of examples?

Comment: @fev I did no research beyond the number of Google returns for each expression. They are quite close: 118M citations for "for" and 201M for "in". Almost a technical tie.

Comment: @CarlosGouveia - your Google search tells you that they are both  commonly  used and possibly correct. It is a question of nuances.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for the complete expression shows that  "*in*"is much preferred.

[in](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20observed%20in%20all%20cases%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[for](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20observed%20for%20all%20cases%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[image]

A similar result is verifiable for the present tense. Therefore,  it seems preferable to use "in".

Answer (score 1):

"... in all cases" might imply that something is being applied to the cases mentioned earlier.

"... for all cases" might imply that something is being applied to all cases in general.

As we can see, complete sentences would be better to decide which word to use.